# How to set up timezone for date coming from view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called 'events' and I have a column called 'scheduled_at', which is of type 'DATETIME WITH TIME ZONE', and I also have a specific column `time_zone` of type string to know the time zone it was selected from the user.

My **form.html.erb** has the following inputs to select date and time from user:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label 'When' %>
  <%= form.date_select :scheduled_at %>
  <%= form.time_select :scheduled_at, ignore_date: true %>
  <%= form.label 'Timezone' %>
  <%= form.time_zone_select("time_zone", nil, default: "Eastern Time (US & Canada)") %>
</div>
```

My **controller** looks like this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.save!
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:scheduled_at, :time_zone)
  end
end
```

This is storing the `scheduled_at` and `time_zone` in the database, but I would like to be able to add the offset to the `scheduled_at` by using the string in `time_zone`. When I look at the params, I see this: `"scheduled_at(1i)"=>"2020", "scheduled_at(2i)"=>"5", "scheduled_at(3i)"=>"31", "scheduled_at(4i)"=>"10", "scheduled_at(5i)"=>"20", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`

How can I modify `scheduled_at` in params, so that when is stored in the DB is considers the offset that is specified in the `time_zone` param?

Comment: I would read this, I think you have everything you need in there https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones